# Fixing up display tables in an Angular 6 project

Tags: c#, mysql, angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

I'm doing a small project using a combination of Angular 6, c#, and MySQL. I'm at the point where I'm trying to display data from two different MySQL tables together but my formatting keeps getting thrown off. Whenever I include the call from the other table it pushes the debit and credit heading to the side. I'm trying to fix this but don't know-how.

Here's the output I keep getting when I mash the tables together[image]

Trying to get table headings somewhat similar to this 
[image]

Here's what I'm currently doing in code. I have a journal component where the whole table is being displayed without any styling on the css.

jr.component.html

```
<table class="table table-hover e-table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Created By</th>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let transaction of viewTransactions">
    <tr>
      <td>{{transaction.createDate | date: 'M/d/yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{transactionType[transaction.type]}}</td>
      <td>{{transaction.createdBy.fullName}}</td>
      <!-- This is where other component is being pulled in -->
      <td><app-journal-entries-list [entries]="transaction.entries"></app-journal-entries-list></td>
      <td>{{transaction.description}}</td>
      <td class="text-center align-middle">
        <span class="d-block" *ngIf="!canUserPost() || transaction.status != transactionStatusType.Pending"
        [ngClass]="{'text-dark': transaction.status == transactionStatusType.Pending, 'text-success': transaction.status == transactionStatusType.Approved, 'text-danger': transaction.status == transactionStatusType.Rejected}">{{transactionStatusType[transaction.status]}}</span>
        <div *ngIf="canUserPost() && transaction.status == transactionStatusType.Pending">
          <button class="btn btn-dark w-100 mb-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-resolve-journal-entry" [attr.data-approve]="true" [attr.data-transaction]="transaction.id">Approve</button>
          <button class="btn btn-dark w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-resolve-journal-entry" [attr.data-approve]="false" [attr.data-transaction]="transaction.id">Reject</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the other component where the information from the second MySQL table is being pulled in. The css doesn't hav styling here either

jre.component.html

```
<table class="table entries-table">
  <tr *ngFor="let entry of getDebits()">
    <td>{{entry.account.name}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.amount | currency}}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let entry of getCredits()">
    <td> {{entry.account.name}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{entry.amount | currency}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense. You are creating a new td with content which is filled by a new table and takes up as much space as it needs.

What you need to do really is merge the information in the initial data source.

You can pass the `entry` instead of the entries in the component and instead of creating a new table update the values of the entry with the new values and show them as you do with the already made values.